# Как в COCOA API узнать размер каталога, пакета и.т.д?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Размер файла в COCOA API узнать довольно просто, например:

```
NSNumber *value = nil;
[url getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
NSUInteger size = [value unsignedLongLongValue];
NSLog(@"File size: %li", size);
```

Но вот как, примерно таким же простым способом, можно узнать размер каталога?

Сейчас что бы получить размер каталога я использую методом рекурсивного перебора, например так:

```
off_t sizeForFolderStat(const char *path)
        {
            off_t size = 0;

            DIR *directory;
            directory = opendir(path);

            if (directory == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "could not open directory '%s'\n", path);
                fprintf(stderr, "error is %d/%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            struct dirent *entry;
            while ( (entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
                char filename[MAXPATHLEN];
                int result;
                struct stat statbuf;

                if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                snprintf(filename, MAXPATHLEN, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);

                result = lstat(filename, &statbuf);
                if (result != 0) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "could not stat '%s': %d/%s\n", entry->d_name, errno, strerror(errno));
                    continue;
                }

                if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
                    size += sizeForFolderStat(filename);
                } else {
                    size += statbuf.st_size;
                }
            }

            closedir(directory);

            return size;  
}
```

Эта функция работает довольно быстро, но когда каталог содержит много вложений она может хорошо нагружать процессор.

В поисках простых способов получить размер каталога я обнаружил что с помощью класса `NSMetadataItem` можно очень просто и быстро получить размер приложения:

```
NSUInteger size = 0;
NSNumber *isApp;
[url getResourceValue:&isApp forKey:NSURLIsApplicationKey error:nil];
if ([isApp boolValue]) {
    NSMetadataItem *metadata = [[NSMetadataItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
    size = [[metadata valueForAttribute:@"kMDItemFSSize"] unsignedLongLongValue];
}
```

По сути .app это тоже каталог но для обычных каталогов(папок) или пакетов этот способ возвращает только размер папки (примерно 4Kb), а не полный размер каталога включая размер всего его содержимого.
Я подозреваю что для пакетов или каталогов(папок) тоже есть подобные способы - быстро и просто получить размер каталога включая размер всего его содержимого.

Если кто-то знает как это сделать пожалуйста поделитесь опытом.
Или расскажите как вы получаете размер каталогов?

Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: а зачем вам это?

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko зачем изобретать велосипед. В OS должны быть средства которые позволяют получить размер каталога без накладных расходов.

Comment: я в смысле зачем вам знать размер каталога, что за задачу вы решаете

Comment: @Max Mikheyenko в моем случае это дополнительная информация, которую пользователь может выбрать из списка.

Comment: а как ее использует пользователь? можете весь юз кейс написать

Comment: @Toly, судя по всему, более простого способа, чем перебор, нет. Все решения которые я видел, предлагают решать такую задачу именно рекурсивным перебором. Кстати, это верно не только для OSX, но и для Windows. Там фреймворк тоже не имеет для этого метода " из коробки".